# Is there a way to get lift-json to auto-convert numeric string fields to numeric type?

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I'm using lift-json to deserialize simple objects from a POST request.  Example:

```
{"id": "35", "name": "My topic", "slug": "my-slug", "imageUrl": "http://foo.bar/image.png"}
```

class definition:

```
class Topic(var id: Option[Long], var name: String, val slug: String, val imageUrl: String)
```

Then I use

`read[Topic](jsonString)`

Is it possible to get json-lift to read the id as a Long automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by converting the JSON.

```
val json = parse("""{"id": "35", "name": "My topic", ...}""")
json transform { case JField("id", JString(s)) => JField("id", JInt(s.toInt)) }
```

And then extract a case class from that transformed JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to do it without parsing twice, but this will do.